# Data Factory Web task - getting full output from a post

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am passing json data to a post request via a web task.
The body contains a number of records that are to be saved by the api.

The body returned contains a status per record sent, but within the webtask i cannot see the over all status of the post request.

In postman, the overall status shows up like below:
[image]

This status and response code (429 in this case) is not visible in the output of the webtask.

Is anyone aware if i can view this in the webtask, as its clearly visible via postman.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's any way to get this; some time ago the MS response was to create a fn app to capture it and call that from adf :)
However you can at least distinguish 2xx from 4xx by using the On Success and On Failure dependencies in the pipeline

Comment: Unfortunately not. In this case the API can return a http 200 but the header has a message saying the API is overloaded and I need to wait a specified amount of seconds before trying again.

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty sure it's supposed to return something like 419 in a case like that; but I guess it's an external and you have no control over it.